# how to import an UTC timestamp to Luxon as it is? (Migrating from Moment)

Tags: javascript, datetime, ecmascript-6, momentjs, luxon

I have this line in my app:

```
const createdOn: moment.Moment = moment.utc(created_on)
```

`created_on` comes from an api endpoint like in this format:

```
{ 
  ...,
  created_on: "2019-03-08T15:32:26.285Z",
}
```

This basically imports `created_on` as an UTC timezone. `created_on` is also `UTC`. So, this method does not break the timezone and import UTC properly. Also I have this one:

That generates current timestamp in UTC timezone.

```
moment.utc()
```

**Note that**, If I just import date to moment and then convert it to UTC, my time goes wrong. Moment by default assumes given date is equal to current visitors timezone. I need to import time as it is. Which is UTC all the time.

What is the equivelant on `Luxon`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`DateTime.utc`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/datetime.js~DateTime.html#static-method-utc) and you can have a look at [For Moment users](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/manual/moment.html) section of Luxon's manual.

You can find in the [Creation](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/manual/moment.html#creation) section:

> ```
> Operation           | Moment            | Luxon                   | Notes
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> From UTC civil time | moment.utc(Array) | DateTime.utc(Number...) | Moment also uses moment.utc() to take other arguments. In Luxon, use the appropriate method and pass in the { zone: 'utc'} option
> ```

So, if your input is a string, you can use `from` method (like [`fromISO`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/datetime.js~DateTime.html#static-method-fromISO)) using `{zone: 'utc'}` option

Here a live sample:

```js
const DateTime = luxon.DateTime;
const nowLuxon = DateTime.utc();
console.log(nowLuxon.toISO(), nowLuxon.toMillis());

const nowMoment = moment.utc();
console.log(nowMoment.format(), nowLuxon.valueOf());

const created_on = "2019-03-08T15:32:26.285Z";
const createdOnLuxon = DateTime.fromISO(created_on, { zone: 'utc'});
console.log(createdOnLuxon.toISO(), createdOnLuxon.toMillis());

const createdOnMoment = moment.utc(created_on);
console.log(createdOnMoment.format(), createdOnMoment.valueOf());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@1.21.3/build/global/luxon.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: But my `created_on` variable is a string comes from an api endpoint. `utc()` seems only accepting Array or objects but not string.

Comment: @Pratha as stated in the doc quotation: _In Luxon, use the appropriate method and pass in the { zone: 'utc'} option_, anyway if you provide a sample value for `created_on` I can update my snippet.

Comment: @Pratha I've edited the answer including the string sample.